# Table <tbody> width broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm doing some data id href content show/hide with css/js but the width of tbody has not taken all the width of table after the jquery took action :

First tbody view after reloaded

[image]

After go to another tbody

[image]

html:

```
<table>
                    <tr style="background: steelblue;">
                        <td colspan="3" style="background: steelblue;"><h4>Total Users: <%= users.length %></h4></td>
                    </tr>
                <tbody id="1" class="userTable">

                    <% var k=0; for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                        <td >
                            <%= users[i].username %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="<%= users[i]._id%>/edit">Edit</a>
                            <form style="display: inline" action="<%= users[i]._id%>/delete?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                               
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>
                    <% var k=1; var length = users.length-5; while(length > 0){ if(length>5){ %>
                <tbody class="userTable" id="<%= k+1%>" style="display: none">
                    <% for(var i=5*k; i<5*k+5; i++){  %>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                        <td >
                            <%= users[i].username %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="<%= users[i]._id%>/edit">Edit</a>
                            <form style="display: inline" action="<%= users[i]._id%>/delete?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>
                    <% length -= 5; %>
                    <% k++; } else { %>
                <tbody class="userTable" id="<%= k+1 %>" style="display: none">
                    <% for(var i=5*k; i < length+5*k; i++){ %>
                    <tr>
                            <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= users[i].username %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="<%= users[i]._id%>/edit">Edit</a>
                                <form style="display: inline" action="<%= users[i]._id%>/delete?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>
                    <% length-= 5;}} %>
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="3" style="width: 1px">
                            <% var k=0; var length = users.length; while(length>0){if(length>=5){ for(var i=0; i<5; i+=5){ %>
                            <a href="#<%= k+1 %>" class="btn tableBtn"><%= k+1 %></a>
                            <% } length-=5; k++; %>

                            <% }else { for(var i=5*k; i<length+5*k; i+=length){ %>
                                <a href="#<%= k+1 %>" class="btn tableBtn"><%= k+1 %></a>
                                <input type="number" id="searchTable">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs searchTableBtn">Go</a>
                            <% } length-=5;}} %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

css:

```
<style>
    td:nth-of-type(odd) {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    td {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    tr{ 
         background: gainsboro;
    }
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: white;
    }
    table {
        margin: 30px auto;
        background: white;
        width: 300px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #888888;
    }
    #searchTable {
        width: 15%;
    }
```

jquery:

```
$(".tableBtn").click(function(){
$(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "block"});
});
$("#searchTable").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(".searchTableBtn").attr("href", "#"+id);
});
$(".searchTableBtn").click(function(){
    $(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "block"}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `tr` should be in either a `tbody` or `thead` or `tfoot`. They should not be directly inside the `table` element. You should similarly have *only one* `tbody` element inside a table.

Also you're using `$("" + id).css({display: "block"});` to "re-display" `tbody` elements. `tbody`'s default display property is `display:table-row-group` not `block`;

Your html formatting makes it very difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. I would suggest you look at rendering the entire table, and using the pagination links you're generating to show/hide the entire `table` rather than the interior `tbody`'s.

---

### Suggested Alteration to code

I would suggest that you instead use the table just for the tabular data, and separate out the pagination and heading into their own elements. This way you can have multiple table elements, and toggle their visibility with your js.

**HTML Generation code**

```
<%
    /*
        Takes an array, and a "chunk" size
        returns an array grouped into "chunks" of the specified size
        if there are a non-exact number of items to equal a whole chunk, the
        last chunk will have less than a whole chunk's worth of items in it
    */
    var chunkArray = function(array, chunk){
        var temparray;
        if(!chunk){
            chunk = 5;
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i+=chunk) {
            temparray = array.slice( i, i+chunk );
        }
        return temparray;
    }
    var chunkSize = 5;
    var usersLength = users.length;
    var userChunks = chunkArray(users, chunkSize);
    var userChunkLength = userChunks.length;
%>
<div class="userTableContainer">
    <div class="userTableHeading">
        <h4>Total Users: <%= users.length %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="userTablePages">
        <!-- begin pages tables -->
        <% for(var page = 0; page < userChunkLength; page++){ %>
            <table class="userTable">
                <tbody>
                    <!-- begin page users rows -->
                    <% for(var i = 0, len = userChunks[page].length; i < len; i++){ %>
                        <% var currentUser = userChunks[page][i]; %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= (page * chunkSize) + (i+1) %></td>
                            <td >
                                <%= currentUser.username %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="<%= currentUser._id%>/edit">Edit</a>
                                <form style="display: inline" action="<%= currentUser._id%>/delete?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    <% } %>
                    <!-- end page users rows -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <% } %>
        <!-- end pages tables -->
    </div>
    <div class="userTableFooter">
        <!-- begin pagination buttons -->
        <% for(var page = 1; page <= userChunkLength; page++){ %>
                <a href="#<%= page %>" class="btn tableBtn"><%= page %></a>
        <% } %>
        <!-- end pagination buttons -->
        <!-- begin page go to input -->
        <% if(userLength > 5){ %>
                <input type="number" id="searchTable">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs searchTableBtn">Go</a>
        <% } %>
        <!-- end page go to input -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated CSS**

```
.userTableContainer {
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #888888;
}
.userTableHeading{
    background:steelblue;
    padding:10px;
}
.userTableFooter{
    padding:10px;
}
.userTable{
    margin:0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.userTable tr{
    background: gainsboro;
}
.userTable tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: white;
}
.userTable td {
    padding: 10px;
}
#searchTable {
    width: 15%;
}
```

**Updated JS**

```
$(".tableBtn").click(function(){
    $(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "table"});
});
$("#searchTable").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(".searchTableBtn").attr("href", "#"+id);
});
$(".searchTableBtn").click(function(){
    $(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "table"}); 
});
```

Comment: solved! thanks for the answer! I just want to select every 5 tr and put it in a group but first i tried span but it didn't work so i had to use tbody! So is there any way to group elements wihout tbody in table?

Comment: @HữuLinh, I'm looking at getting you an example that "chunks" your array, and then places everything in a `div` with an internal `table` element that represents a "page".. it will make more semantic sense this way, and you shouldnt need to keep adjusting your loop.

Comment: @HữuLinh, updated with suggested changes, as i dont have a way to generate your code myself, it is largely untested, but should work as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `block` use `table-header-group`

```
$(".tableBtn").click(function(){
$(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "table-header-group"});
});
$("#searchTable").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(".searchTableBtn").attr("href", "#"+id);
});
$(".searchTableBtn").click(function(){
    $(".userTable").css({display: "none"});
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("" + id).css({display: "table-header-group"}); 
});
```

Comment: i tried it but 'table-row-group' is working for me. Thanks